# can you tel sqlite3 to give you just the year of a date?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

so i'm using

```
select <name> from <table>;
```

to get a datetime (in this case a real) out of a sqlite3 database. is there a convenient way to say something like

```
select <name>(except only give me the year) from <table>
```

so as to get, say, 2021 instead of 01-01-2021 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select strftime("%Y", nice_column) from nice_table;
```

The above should work. Read more about `strftime` at the page: [SQLite date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)